# Search list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this python code, which is used to access dictionary elements using dotted notation.

```
foo = {
    "bar" : {
        "baz" : [ {"boo" : "hoo"} , {"baba" : "loo"} ]
    }
}
```

```
class Map(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Map, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for arg in args:
            if isinstance(arg, dict):
                for k, v in arg.iteritems():
                    if isinstance(v, dict):
                        v = Map(v)
                    if isinstance(v, list):
                        self.__convert(v)
                    self[k] = v

        if kwargs:
            for k, v in kwargs.items():
                if isinstance(v, dict):
                    v = Map(v)
                elif isinstance(v, list):
                    self.__convert(v)
                self[k] = v

    def __convert(self, v):
        for elem in range(0, len(v)):
            if isinstance(v[elem], dict):
                v[elem] = Map(v[elem])
            elif isinstance(v[elem], list):
                self.__convert(v[elem])

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return self.get(attr)

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        self.__setitem__(key, value)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        super(Map, self).__setitem__(key, value)
        self.__dict__.update({key: value})

    def __delattr__(self, item):
        self.__delitem__(item)

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        super(Map, self).__delitem__(key)
        del self.__dict__[key]
```

```
if foo.bar.baz[1].baba == "loo":
    print("True")
```

The above code works fine,  but i would like to compare values of dictioary with out index value, like this,

```
if foo.bar.baz.baba == "loo":
    print("True")
```

Basically it must internally search in all objects in list.
What changes should be made to get that result.

Comment: What about modifying your `__convert` method to created a merged `Map` isntead of a `list` of `Map`s?

Comment: This is a pretty inefficient way to do this, btw, you are essentially doubling your memory requirements. There's no good reason to implement `__setitem__` and then do `self.__dict__.update({key:value})`, (which, btw, is an inefficent way of writign `self.__dict__[key] = value`)

Comment: I am using this only to get items not modify it. Other methods there will be removed

Comment: @Adirio, Yes merging would work,  I replaced ```v[elem] = Map(v[elem])``` with ```v = Map({k:v for k,v in v[elem].items()})```. It doesn't seem correct.

Comment: @Mohan you will have to return the `Map` and assign it in where you call the function: `v = self.__convert(v)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
class Map(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for arg in args:
            if isinstance(arg, dict):
                for k, v in arg.items():
                    self[k] = self.__convert(v)

        if kwargs:
            for k, v in kwargs.items():
                self[k] = self.__convert(v)

    def __convert(self, v):
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            return self.__convert_dict(v)

        if isinstance(v, (list, tuple)):
            return self.__convert_list(v)

        if isinstance(v, (str, int, float, bool)):  # return basic types unmodified
            return v

        raise TypeError  # An exception will be raised if some other type is passed

    def __convert_dict(self, dct):
        return Map(dct)

    def __convert_list(self, lst):
        # Lists and tuples may be of basic elements, in which case we want to keep them
        # as they are, or of Map-convertible types, in which case we want to merge all them
        m = Map()
        rest = []
        for v in lst:
            v = self.__convert(v)
            if isinstance(v, Map):
                m.update(v)
            else:
                rest.append(v)

        # TODO: if we have a list with both kind of elements we have to decide what to do
        if len(m) and len(rest):
            raise ValueError

        if len(m):
            return m
        return rest

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return self.get(attr)

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        self.__setitem__(key, value)

    def __delattr__(self, item):
        self.__delitem__(item)
```

Usage:

```py
foo = Map({
    "bar" : {
        "baz" : [ {"boo" : "hoo"} , {"baba" : [1, 2]} ]
    }
})
foo.bar.baz.baba  # [1, 2]
```

In a comment, it was requested to replace the merge behavior of lists of dicts to incremental integer suffixes for the keys, that can be achieved by replacing the `__convert_list` method by the following:

```py
    def __convert_list(self, lst):
        # Lists and tuples may be of basic elements, in which case we want to keep them
        # as they are, or of Map-convertible types, in which case we want to merge all them
        m = Map()
        rest = []
        for v in lst:
            v = self.__convert(v)
            if isinstance(v, Map):
                for key, value in v.items():
                    if key in m:
                        i = 1
                        while key + str(i) in n:
                            i += 1
                        m[key + str(i)] = value
                    else:
                        m[key] = value
            else:
                rest.append(v)

        # TODO: if we have a list with both kind of elements we have to decide what to do
        if len(m) and len(rest):
            raise ValueError

        if len(m):
            return m
        return rest
```

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I think this solution removes all the memory duplication and unneeded calls, but, would you mind checking?

Comment: That is true,   ```dicti = {
    "emails":[{
        "type":"home",
        "value":"abc@gmail.com"
    },
    {
        "type":"other",
        "value":"def@gmail.com"
    }]
}``` results in ```{'emails': {'type': 'other', 'value': 'def@gmail.com'}}``` which is not correct

Comment: You said in the comments that merging the dicts when inside an array was a valid solution. The example you write here is not mergeable as they share keys and keys cant be duplicated inside a dict, the last values will be kept and the previous ones dropped. In your example, what would `dicti.emails.type` be? Because `dicti.emails[0].type` is "home" while `dicti.emails[1].type` is "other".

Comment: Pardon me, the array in my use case will have objects with same same key,  just like

Comment: Pardon me, the array in my use case will have objects with same same key,  just like ```"type":"other"``` and ```"type":"home"```.  Update replaces duplicates.  What changes could be made.

Comment: `dicti.emails.type` without the index will not know where to get the type from. Always from the first item? Always from the last item? Iterating over the list to find the first one that has it? Or the last one that has it? By merging you always get the last one that has it. If you define properly the behavior in this case I can modify it.

Comment: essentially, Iterating over the list to find all objects that has it. I should be able to do something logically like this,  ```if (dicti.emails.type == "home") and (dicti.emails.type == "other")``` to return the document

Comment: `(dicti.emails.type == "home") and (dicti.emails.type == "other")` is always `False` from a logical point of view. That behavior can be achieved by overloading the equality operator `__eq__`, but first you would have to create a `Array` class similar to `Map` but for lists of Map (lists of other objects should not be `Array`), and probably an `Item` class for anything that is not a `Map` or an `Array` and then overload the three `__eq__` methods (`Map`, `Array` and `Item`) but the logic will become quite complex. And it seriously makes no sense: `(a == 1) && (a == 2)` should be `false`.

Comment: Is there any other logic that we can use other than dictionary merge?

Comment: How about, we add duplicates to dictionary by appending incremental numbers to it, like```dicti = {'emails': {'type': 'other', 'value': 'abc@gmail.com', 'type1':"home", 'value1':"def@gmail.com"}}``` and access it by ```dicti.emails.type<any int here which is optional>```

Comment: @Mohan I added an alternative `__convert_list` method that should behave as you requested. Just replace by the previous method and you will get incremental integer sufixes for repeated keys.